# Using DateTime To Capture Upcoming Date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this as my syntax which when I step through the code it provides the accurate date, however when I use it to create the Directory it gives me an inaccurate date (date used to create the folder is 33.22.15_Created Programmatically"

```
DateTime upcomingMonday = DateTime.Now;

while (upcomingMonday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
upcomingMonday = upcomingMonday.AddDays(1);
}

Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveLocation + upcomingMonday.ToString("mm.dd.yy") + "_Created Programattically\\");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mm` is for minutes. Use:

```
upcomingMonday.ToString("MM.dd.yy")
```

`MM` gets the month, padded with a `0` if necessary (January => `01`, December => `12`).

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).